# Stop a function from to break infinite recursion

Tags: c

I'm stuck on this part from this exercise that I'm doing. I need to take two numbers and output the numbers until it hits zero and then till the same value but negative. For example:

Input:
`10, 2`

Output:
`10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10`

I can make it go down to zero but i use the zero to stop the recursion I don't have an idea how can i use the zero to make it go up till the initial number.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int recursion(int n, int m) {
if(n == 0) {
    return n;
} else if(n > 0) {
    printf("%d ", n);
    return recursion(n - m, m);
} else if(n <= 0) {
    printf("%d ", n);
    return recursion(n + m, m);
}


 }

int main() {

    int n, m;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    printf("%d ", recursion(n, m));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use `0` as the terminator? You know the *real* terminator, and there’s no need to do anything but a single arithmetic operation each time through.

Comment: @DaveNewton what should i use? Edit: I think i should use n but n decreases every iteration of the function so how can i store the initial value of n?

Comment: ... maybe read the problem statement again? It’s explicitly stated.

Comment: Alternatively, you could instead print the negative numbers *on the back side* of the recursive call chain.  That is, print x; recurse; print -x.

Comment: Do you have to use recursion? This is a simple for loop: `for (i = n; i >= -n; i -= m)`, where `n` is the original input.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes i know it's simpler without recursion but i must use recursion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can you please elaborate a bit how should i do that?

Comment: @DaveNewton If i understood the problem I wouldn't  be here.

Comment: I already gave you pseudocode, @Stefan.  I'm not going to write your whole assignment for you.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post the actual exercise text/description so that we can see what exactly is asked of you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the intent of the exercise is to have the function print the numbers while proceeding through the recursion and print their negations on the way out:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void recursion(int n, int m)
{
    printf("%d ", n);
    if (n <= 0)
        return;
    recursion(n-m, m);
    printf("%d ", -n);
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    recursion(n, m);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you and i just tested it out. Can you tell me why It doesn't work for 7 and 3 where n = 7 and m = 3?

Comment: @Stefan: The code stops when `n == 0`. With 7 and 3, the steps are 7, 4, 1, −2. You might want to change the stop condition to `n <= 0`. However, you have not shown us the actual problem statement, so we do not know.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: How does the last printf in the function prints the number in reverse but not duplicated because in my understanding it should print the one after the other and your function prints them only after the <= 0.

Comment: @Stefan: The function `recursion` prints `n`, then it calls `recursion` to process smaller numbers, then it prints `-n`. The printing of `-n` occurs after the processing of smaller numbers.

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere now. Can you elaborate how the last printf("%d", n) contains all the values in reversed order after the N becomes <=0?

Comment: @Stefan: It does not contain the values. In learning about programming, you should have learned about *control flow*. There is an imaginary point where the computer is executing, and that point moves through the code. It flows into the first `printf`, then into the function call `recursion`, then into the next `printf`. during that function call, control flow moves through the `printf` again (but with different argument/parameter values), then through the function call again, and so on. The fact that all the function calls are evaluated first means the second `printf` calls happen later.

Comment: This answer doesn't work when `n` isn't divisible by `m`, which is why it won't work with `7` and `3`, the result should be `7`, `4`, `1`, `-2`, `-5`, not `7`, `4`, `1`, `-1`, `-4`, `-7`. A different solution will need to be constructed.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: We do not know what the output should be when the first number is not a multiple of the second because a complete problem statement has not been provided. The question does not state the output should be an arithmetic sequence that extends into the negative numbers.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Thinking about it more, I think it quite likely the problem statement only asks multiples to be supported. The circumstances suggest this is an exercise for students who are just learning about recursion for the first time. It likely does not ask them to handle exceptional cases and is intended to give very simple output that illustrates descending into the recursion and ascending out of it. If so, it is intended to be symmetric, and students may even have been given only one case (10, 2) to support. It is **intended** to be a simple exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer my best to answer this question. But keep in mind that this solution only works when the subtracting number (i.e m) subtracts (m) in such a way that at some point it will give you 0, when you keep on subtracting m, if it doesn't then this solution will also keep on recursively goes on.

```
`int recursion(int n, int m) {
   if(n == 0) {
     printf("0 ");
   } else {
       printf("%d ", n);
       return recursion(n - m, m);
       printf("%d ", -n);
   } 
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the base case of recursion is not good. I adjust the base case so that it can stop correctly. Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int recursion(int n, int m, int upperLimit) {
    if (n < upperLimit && abs(n-m) >= upperLimit) {
        return n;
    }
    printf("%d ", n);
    return recursion(n - m, m, upperLimit);
}

int main() {

    int n, m;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    printf("%d ", recursion(n, m, n));


    return 0;
```

}